# Webapp to POS receipt printer connection

Tags: javascript, web-applications, printing

I am working on connecting and Epson TM88 printer to my webapp to print receipts.

- Epson model TM-T88V-i.
- Connected to LAN.
- Ping response OK.
- Printing status sheet OK.

I have access to printer configuration page just with printers IP address.
http://10.0.x.xxx/
Printer ID is 32 from there.

The URL provided in manual is : var url = 'http://10.0.x.x/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=32other_printer&timeout=6000';

Using this url returns object not found. And through code it returns 405 (Method not allowed).

PART 2:How do I determine printers connected in network using JS?

Comment: From a web browser, you cannot do that.

Comment: but in sdk guide they give example to access the printer from a web page

Comment: https://pos.epson.com/developers/LicenseAgreement.htm?AssetId=26683&ReturnUrl=http%3a%2f%2fpos.epson.com%2fmobilesdks%2f I am following th exact process.

Comment: I have facing same issue that 405 Method not allowed.

Comment: @Pointy What could be other ways to print from browser? Which require less installation from client side?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you make a cross-site xml request and your browser preflights the request. The preflight request uses the OPTIONS verb, which the printer's server does not allow.

[This guide](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/.) is a good resource on the topic. In the comments, a response to a user with a similar problem explains that "You can remove the preflighting by not adding cookies (withCredentials=false) and not setting any headers."